# PHP Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php

I have this line in my PHP function :

```
$extension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));
```

and in action I see this error:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in ...
```

how do fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Technically that would be

```
$parts = explode('.',$fileName);
$extension = strtolower(end($parts));
```

but

```
$ext = strtolower( pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) );
```

is what you should use.

see http://docs.php.net/function.pathinfo